# Using AJAX with multiple submit buttons

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-submit

I have a html form which includes 2 submit buttons.

These two submit buttons connect to a php file which runs statements based on the submits. The php file runs correctly, although when I use AJAX to send the data and to prevent to redirect, the information does not reach the php file, despite the php statements working fine when I am testing.

Interesting, when I use a PHP with just one submit and without `if/else` the information reaches the php for processing without redirection, so the problem probably lies with the two submits, and because my AJAX can't handle or distinguish the submits.

I attach my code

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" name="first_submit" value="Frist" /> 
<input type="submit" name="second_submit" value="Second" />
```

**AJAX**

```
<script>
     $(function () {
    $('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function () {
                location.reload();
            } 
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
    </script>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['first_submit'])) {
             //do something

    } 
    elseif (isset($_POST['second_submit'])) {
               //do something
    }

    else {
    //do something
    }

?>
```

Comment: ``` $('#form').on('click', functi```... should be on the "submit" event, not the click event. Also, you'll need to change ```data: $(this).serialize()``` to ```data: $('#form').serialize()```

Comment: use <input type='button'>..and make onclick of the button

Comment: They way you are using the program is wrong.why you need two submit button?

Comment: I am sorry, I have used ''submit", just the 'click'  remained here from testing. I corrected my code.

Comment: @SloanThrasher `$(this).serialize()` should work perfectly, because the context will be the form element.

Comment: I need two submit, because In my PHP there are two SQL query, so If i click on the first submit the first query will be executed,  and I have a chart which will be displaying the data from query.

Comment: @bummm26 please show us how your `<form>` element is declared.

Comment: @bummm26 "I need two submit, because In my PHP there are two SQL query" this should work, but a more conventional approach from a UX perspective would be to use something like a dropdownlist or radio buttons to let the user choose which option they want. then you'd only need one submit button, but you can have as many options as you like

Comment: `<form  id="form" action="test.php" method="POST"  >   From date               
      <input type="text" class="button" name="from_date" /><br /> To date               
      <input type="text" class="button" name="to_date" /><br />         
     <input type="submit" name="first_submit" value="First submit" /> 
     <input type="submit" name="second_submit" value="Second submit" /> 
    </form>`

Comment: Your question is similar to this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/43364146/1816407

Comment: ok thanks but in future please edit the question with such additions - code in comments is hard to read

Comment: when the ajax runs, can you check the request in the network tab in the browser and tell us what values are serialized there in the request body? in other words, is the button data being serialised and sent correctly? then we can see if the problem is client- or server- side

Comment: also, why are you refreshing the page immediately when the ajax returns? If you're going to do that, why use ajax at all? A conventional postback would work the same, and you would have only 1 trip to the server, and not 2. Plus you are discarding whatever response the server is giving you from ajax, and doing nothing with it. It seems a bit pointless to me.

Comment: @ ADyson  I got 304 not modified message

Comment: @ ADyson I refresh the page because  my chart ( ChartJS) use the query result which stored in a txt. So When the php queries finished, the result stored and after the refresh the chart able to load the data. I know that this solution is ugly but I am very newby in coding.

Comment: In that case I would just forget the ajax, do a straight postback and immediately run the query there and then display the chart, all in one server request. Much more efficient. And use a dropdown or radio button control to select your query, rather than 2 submits - it will give you less problems.

Comment: **If I use radio buttons instead of submits the code working perfectly. Thank @ ADyson the help!**

Answer (score -1):

try to prevent the default action by using this code

Jquery

`event.preventDefault()`

so that default action of the event will not be triggered

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same result, the submits didn't reach the `PHP` for processing. If I use one submit, the code working fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can create and Use some session variable to achieve it easily.

E.g. $_SESSION['validate'].

HTML and PHP Code for buttons

```
<button type="submit" id="first_submit" style="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['validate'])?'display:none':'';?>">first submit</button>
<button type="submit" id="second_submit" style="<?php echo isset($_SESSION['validate'])?'':'display:none';?>">second submit</button>
```

jquery and ajax Script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#form").on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'handler-file.php',
                data:  new FormData(this),
                dataType: "json",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData:false,
                error:function(error){
                    //your required code or alert
                    alert(error.responseText);
                },
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.status=='1')
                    {
                        //your required code or alert
                        $('#first_submit').hide();
                        $('#second_submit').show();
                    }
                    else if(response.status=='2')
                    {
                        //your required code or alert
                        $('#first_submit').show();
                        $('#second_submit').hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //your required code or alert
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Handler PHP File

```
<?php
session_start();

$result['status']='0';
$result['error']='';

if(!isset($_SESSION['validate']))
{
    if(!isset($_FILES['file'])) 
    {
        $result['error'].='[Er-02 file missing!]';
    }
    else
    {
        //your other code
        $_SESSION['validate'] = true;
        $result['status']='1';
    }
}
else if($_SESSION['validate']==true)
{
    if(!isset($_FILES['file'])) 
    {
        $result['error'].='[Er-03 Validation file missing!]';
    }
    else
    {
        //your other code
        unset($_SESSION['validate']);
        $result['status']='2';
    }
}
else
{
    $result['error'].='[Er-01 Invalid source!]';
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

?>

It may not be the optimal or efficient solution. My level of experience is not too much, so I came up with this solution what served my purpose best after all the solutions available but with their limitations. This was not anywhere so thought to write it here.

Note: You may notice it includes some other parts like response, success and error handling between presentation, script and backend file.

Hope it helps!